# Search for question mark in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

In Kibana, I have a field that contains a question mark. The goal is to create a filter that excludes all entries containing a question mark in the field.

Escaping the question mark with "\" seems not to work. I would have expected any of the two below to work.

- `\?`
- `/\?/` or `/\\?/`

Comment: If the string field is analyzed, the question mark has probably been eliminated during the analysis process when the document was indexed. Hence you won't be able to search it. What is the mapping of your field?

Comment: The field is analyzed. I will try to add a raw field. Thanks

Comment: @Val that fixed the problem for me. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string field is analyzed, the question mark has probably been eliminated during the analysis process when the document was indexed.

Hence why you aren't able to search it.

I suggest creating an additional `not_analyzed` field (or sub-field) in order to achieve what you want.